# Java Swing Null Pointer Exception do-while

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, do-while

I am working on a simple system that collects elements from an array that is chosen through a series of button events, copies it into a new array called 'oneRay' and proceeds to cycle through its elements to test the user on their knowledge. If a user correctly identifies an answer from a prompt, the first element of the 2D array in that section becomes "", and is skipped with this code:

```
        do{
        pick = random.nextInt(oneRay.length);
    }while(!(oneRay[pick][0].equals("")));
```

Which continues to return the aforementioned exception. The following code creates random as a member of the class in question:

```
Random random = new Random()
```

So what could I be doing wrong?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Yes the elements are initialized through a series of switch statements that direct proper the selected array to oneRay

The error report is huge as it is launched as I am trying to build the swing UI, so it tosses failures left and right

Here is what I used for initialization:

```
switch(subject){
    case 1:
        switch(unit){
        case 1: oneRay = new String[Master.SciChemArray_IntroductionANDFirstChapter.length][2];
           for(int i = 0; (Master.SciChemArray_IntroductionANDFirstChapter.length) > i; i++){
               oneRay[i][0] = Master.SciChemArray_IntroductionANDFirstChapter[i][0];oneRay[i][1] = Master.SciChemArray_IntroductionANDFirstChapter[i][1];}
        default: System.exit(0); break;
        } break;
    case 2:
        switch(unit){
        case 1: 
            oneRay = new String[Master.MathaRay_Part2.length][2];
           for(int i = 0; (Master.MathaRay_Part2.length) > i; i++){
               oneRay[i][0] = Master.MathaRay_Part2[i][0]; oneRay[i][1] = Master.MathaRay_Part2[i][1];} break;
        default: System.exit(0); break;
        } break;
```

When creating this setup I pass a number which corresponds to a subject and a unit number, which are then used to copy the relevant array like so ^^

Unit and Subject are passed like so:

```
         mathstatb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l) {
            new SwingImplementation(2, 1);
        }});
```

Whereby a button sends off subject 2 and unit 1

And here are the Errors, now at the bottom, if anyone really wants them:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at wbh.SwingImplementation.<init>(SwingImplementation.java:60)
at wbh.matstatMenu$1.actionPerformed(matstatMenu.java:23)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Has `oneRay` and its elements been initialized?

Comment: I need to see all the code and the whole exception report.

Comment: It's obviously not initialized if you are getting NPE. Post your relevant code.

Comment: did you initialize oneRay to null before the switch case?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that all of the oneRay array values are initalized correctly.

The following line seems most prone for NullPointer. If you try to call .equals() method for null it throws the NullPointer.

```
oneRay[pick][0].equals("");
```

Comment: I cannot see why there would be a null though if my for-loop fills all properly from an array with no null-s; thanks for the contribution I will double check my methods

Comment: @williambrun Either attach a break point in your code and examine the value or add a System.out to dump the value. Your perception and reality don't match, and reality is winning...

Answer (score -1):

It would be more clear if you paste the whole code. In current code, I see the following might be throwing a nullpointer :

```
!(oneRay[pick][0].equals(""))
```

change it to

```
!("".equals(oneRay[pick][0]))
```

Comment: those two statements are the same

Comment: no they are not.. if oneRay[pick][0] is null it will throw a nullpointer while calling equals... but when equals is called for "" it will never throw nullpointer

Comment: it's call yoda code, they aren't the same, that prevent `NullPointerException`

Comment: I did! And alas while there was no NPE, my entire GUI froze as I clicked the Math Button

Comment: Well I really can't tell, is there any way I can see how far the program has moved through the code before freezing? Should I throw in some println checkpoints?

Comment: If you are using an IDE, put debug points. If you find doing that difficult put printlns.